# SQL Server pass in string value and see if it is in a hard-coded list of values and return int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that I have created that for right now I am not touching a database.

Pseudo code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CustomerKeyChecker]
   @ldccode VARCHAR(12)
AS
   @result int = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @listofCodes varchar(200)
    SET @listofCodes = 'CLP, UIC, NSTAR, NSTARB, NSTARC, PSNH'

    -- So lets say that the passed in @ldccode is "CLP" , well then I went to   
    -- set a   @result = 1  

END
```

What is the a decent way to do a substring to search for these codes inside list?

Pseudo code:

```
 substring(@lcdcode, @listOfCodes)    ?
```

Again, for now this is nothing to do with the database, and I understand that someone would say "why even pass this data to sql"   ... there will be sql tables added in later is why ...

Comment: Kindly refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2657/1460189

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may notice that we add a space to the begining and comma to the end of each variable.  This is to prevent false positives i.e. STAR.  You may also notice SIGN(), this will return 1 if a positive number, 0 if not found.

```
Declare @ldccode VARCHAR(12) = 'CLP'
Declare @result int = 0

declare @listofCodes varchar(200)
SET @listofCodes = 'CLP, UIC, NSTAR, NSTARB, NSTARC, PSNH'

Select @result=sign(charindex(' '+@ldccode+',',' '+@listofCodes+','))
```

**Returns**

```
1
```